# Finding loaded angular in a complex cshtml application

Tags: angularjs

I am debugging a .cshtml application (razor?) that has various angular components in it. It looks like there may be several angular instances in various sections through the 'web' project. This is not a single-page app.

My question is less about VS/CS and more about simply reverse-engineering an app to find the controllers, modules and apps.

**The problem:**
The screen I am working on (hereafter called the **'document upload screen'**) does not run the controller; my brackets {{}} show up on-screen.

**My troubleshooting:**
From the main menu, the application flows to a 'questionnaire' module, angular does get loaded:

```
var appModule = angular.module('cmorApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCookies', 'ui.select2', 'ui.utils', 'ui.select', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.keypress', 'ui.calendar', 'monospaced.elastic']);

appModule.run(['$rootScope', '$route', '$window', '$http', '$compile', '$cookies', '$location', '$timeout',
    function ($rootScope, $route, $window, $http, $compile, $cookies, $location, $timeout) {


        if (typeof angular == 'undefined') {
            alert("Angular IS loaded: " + typeof angular);
        }
        else {
            alert("Angular is NOT loaded: " + typeof angular);
        }
```

I **do** see an alert box with **Angular IS loaded: object**

It apparently then loads the controller:

```
appModule.controller('ReferralCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$window', '$filter', 'cm.addressService', 'debounce', 'cm.caseService',
function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $http, $window, $filter, addressService, debounce, caseService) {

    if (typeof angular == 'undefined') {
        alert("Angular IS also loaded: " + typeof angular);
    }
    else {
        alert("Angular is NOT also loaded: " + typeof angular);
    }

    $scope.foo = "foo";
```

I **do** see an alert box with **Angular IS also loaded: object **

There are then a few questionnaire screens, and finally the 'document upload screen', the screen of interest.

```
   <div class="section" ng-controller="ReferralCtrl">
       {{foo}}
       more content
```

It renders with **{{foo}} more content**. In other words, angular does not seem to be running.

And there are no console errors.

I have inserted a script directly into the page to test for angular:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof angular == 'undefined') {
        alert("Angular IS STILL loaded:  " + typeof angular);
    }
    else {
        alert("Angular IS NOT STILL loaded: " + typeof angular);
    }
    <div class="section" ng-controller="ReferralCtrl" style="margin-top:30px;">
    </div>
```

and I **do** see **Angular IS STILL loaded:  object**

So why is the controller not working?

How can I troubleshoot this to figure out why it's not running?
Is there a way of inserting code into the cshtml template (as opposed to in the controller) to directly test if angular is loaded?

Comment: Are you able to see any error at browser console?

Comment: There are no console errors.

Comment: I've been assuming there's something missing, causing it to not work. It hadn't occurred to me there might be something *extra*. Angular has been known to die silently in some circumstances.

It seems to work if there's nothing else on the page, so i'm going to rip stuff out until it starts to work.

Comment: So it seems that you portion of code is just out side of root scope or outside of any controller scope

Comment: How though? 
appModule.controller('ReferralCtrl',...
<div ng-controller="ReferralCtrl"...
seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It was 'ui.select' causing angular to die silently.